# Is it possible remove host from Ansible group?

Tags: loops, ansible, hosts, ansible-inventory, execution-time

I have a set of 20 jump servers `jump_nodes` which has connectivity to a set of 100 destination target servers `dest_nodes`.

Note: We are not sure which of the 20 jump servers has connectivity to which of the 100 destination host.

We have a set of tasks `performtask.yml` that need to be performed on all `dest_nodes` hosts.

Below is the playbook for the same.

```
---

- name: "Play 1"
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item }}"
        groups: jump_nodes
      with_items: "{{ jump_server_list.split('\n') }}"

    - add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item }}"
        groups: dest_nodes
      with_items: "{{ target_server_list.split('\n') }}"

- name: "Play 3"
  hosts: jump_nodes
  tasks:
    - name: Perform tasks on dest_nodes
      include_tasks: performtask.yml
      with_items: "{{ groups['dest_nodes'] }}"
```

The issue with the above approach is that it takes a lot of time i.e `20 X 100 X <number of tasks> = 2000 X <number of tasks>`

My requirement is that if anyone of the `jump_nodes` host is able to successfully connect and perform the task on a particular `dest_nodes` IP say `10.0.0.99`; then this host `10.0.0.99` should be removed from the `dest_nodes` group and other jump servers should simply skip that `dest_nodes` IP.

That way we will be able to considerably reduce the total execution time and the number of tasks.

A feature like `remove_hosts` equivalent to `add_hosts` would have done the trick but I understand that there is no such feature.

Update: With the solution proposed by @Kevin C I'm unable to get the difference between hosts, instead i get a syntax error. Nothing of the below works.

```
groups['dest_nodes' | difference(success_nodes | default([]) )] 
groups['dest_nodes' | difference('success_nodes' | default([]))]
groups[dest_nodes | difference(success_nodes | default([]) )]
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still a bit vague what is expected, and how your current execution looks like.

However, you could create a list of servers which are able to connect from the jumphost to the dest_nodes. This task would take time, but you could use `run_once: true` to limit execution to one host for this task.

Also, you could [use the difference filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters) to exclude items (dest_nodes) from a list. And then execute task `performtask.yml` with a `when` clause.

Ensure to first use:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    list_1: "{{ groups['dest_nodes'] }}"

- set_fact:
    list_2: "{{ groups['success_nodes'] }}"
```

first..

As we spoke in chat, it finally worked!

Comment: I may have not understood completely but, do you mean build a new third list `success_nodes` of successful task performed IPs inside `performtask.yml` and then mention something like this `with_items: "{{ groups['dest_nodes'] |  difference(success_nodes) }}"` ?

Comment: Almost. You should use `when: groups['dest_nodes' | difference(success_nodes)]`

Comment: I tried the following with debug but i get syntax error and not the difference.

` groups['dest_nodes' | difference(success_nodes | default([]) )]
 groups['dest_nodes' | difference('success_nodes' | default([]) )]
 groups[dest_nodes | difference(success_nodes | default([]) )]`

Comment: The output of your comment is not understandable and not readable for me. You could use pastebin. Please, take your time to write concise responses.

Comment: @ Kevin C i updated my reply in the original post for readability.

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. It should be `groups['dest_nodes'] | difference(success_nodes)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221515/discussion-between-ashar-and-kevin-c).

Comment: Post discussion I came to a conclusion that  difference filter does not work for `add_host` but only works for list. Hence, I used @KevinC solution by converting group to lists like here: `- set_fact: dest_list="{{ groups['dest_nodes'] | default([]) }}"` to get this to work. Many Thanks for @KevinC explicit discussion and help !!